# Get the interface IP address from a VM using VirtualBox SDK

Tags: python, sdk, virtual-machine, virtualbox, ip-address

I have had some problems trying to get the virtual machine interface IP address-  I have been able to get its MAC address, the type of adapter it uses, the machine´s mode it´s in and the name of the network it´s connected to, but no I can find out how to get its interface IP address.

```
from vboxapi import VirtualBoxManager
from pprint import pprint
import os

def getAdapterName(madapter):
    attachtype=madapter.attachmentType
    #print(attachtype)
    if attachtype == 4:
        adaptername = madapter.HostOnlyInterface
    elif attachtype == 1:
        adaptername = madapter.NATNetwork
    else:
        adaptername = "NULL"
    return adaptername
    
mgr = VirtualBoxManager(None, None)

vbox = mgr.getVirtualBox()

#The VM has 4 adapters
for m in mgr.getArray(vbox, 'machines'):
    for x in range (4):
        madapter = m.getNetworkAdapter(x)
        adapter=getAdapterName(madapter)
        if adapter != "NULL":
            print("Machine %s in adaptader %d: %s" %(m.name, x+1, adapter))
            print(" Network MAC "+ madapter.MACAddress + ", conecting in mode " + str(madapter.attachmentType))
        else:
            print("\n")
```

I am using as a reference: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.8_RC1/SDKRef.pdf